# Java: show compiler phases like `scalac -Xprint:parser`

Tags: java, scala

`javac -Xprint` only shows the class's API.

i can write a scala program, compile it with `scalac -Xprint:<phase>`, and print out the tree with whatever processing has done at any phase.

i want something that can emit the representation at each of the fundamental stages of java compilation:

```
$ javac -Xshow-phases
             phase name  description
             ----------  -----------
                 parser  parse source into ASTs, perform simple desugaring
                  namer  resolve names, attach symbols to named trees
         packageobjects  load package objects
                  typer  the meat and potatoes: type the trees
         superaccessors  add super accessors in traits and nested classes
              refchecks  reference/override checking, translate nested objects
                erasure  erase types
                flatten  eliminate inner classes
                    jvm  generate JVM bytecode
```

does such an option or tool exist? how could we do this in java?

Comment: You would need to either find or write a Java compiler that has similar options to the Scala compiler. However, A large proportion of these AST manipulations don't happen with Java, so it wouldn't really be as worthwhile.

Comment: (i only want a few things like name resolution; i edited the question to make it clear what i want)

Comment: Javac has nothing like this.